# How to find and fix the performace problems with my voxel engine?

Tags: c#, xna, performance, voxels

I am creating a voxel engine in C# and XNA and many posts I have posted on this site have been due to performace issues, many people suggested using a profiler to help me out. I have done so, and strangely enough, the most functions that are costing me the most performance according to the profiler are the simplest. Here is the output of the profiler:

[image]

and here is the world code:

```
    public bool InBounds(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if ((x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0) ||
            x >= size.X || y >= size.Y || z >= size.Z)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Exists(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            Vector3i regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            Vector3i region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            return !(regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].Blocks[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z].BlockType == BlockType.none);
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void SetLight(int x, int y, int z, int light)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            Vector3i regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            Vector3i region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].QueueForBuild(BufferType.All);

            regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].Blocks[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z].Light = (byte)light;
        }
    }

    public int GetLight(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            // ARRAYS start from ZERO
            // LOGIC starts from ONE

            Vector3i regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            Vector3i region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            return regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].Blocks[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z].Light;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        Block block = GetBlock(x, y, z);

        return block;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            Vector3i regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            Vector3i region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            return regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].Blocks[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z];
        }

        return new Block(BlockType.none);
    }

    public void RemoveBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        Vector3i regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
        Vector3i region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

        Block block = new Block(regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].Blocks[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z].BlockType);

        regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].QueueForBuild(block);
        regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].Blocks[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z].BlockType = BlockType.none;

        lighting.BlockRemoved(block, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(Block block, Vector3 position)
    {
        //position += new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        AddBlock(block, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(Block block, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            Vector3i regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            Vector3i region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].Blocks[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z].BlockType = block.BlockType;

            if (lighting != null)
            {
                lighting.BlockAdded(block, x, y, z);

                if (GetBlock(x, y, z).BlockType == BlockType.waterStill)
                {
                    regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Water);
                    fuilds.WaterQueue.Enqueue(new Flow(x, y, z, 16));
                }
                else
                {
                    regions[region.X, region.Y, region.Z].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Solid);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Vector3i GetRegionPosition(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int regionx = x == 0 ? 0 : x / Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;
        int regiony = y == 0 ? 0 : y / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;
        int regionz = z == 0 ? 0 : z / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;

        return new Vector3i(regionx, regiony, regionz);
    }

    public Vector3i GetRegionalPosition(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int regionx = x == 0 ? 0 : x / Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;
        int X = x % Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;

        int regiony = y == 0 ? 0 : y / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;
        int Y = y % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;

        int regionz = z == 0 ? 0 : z / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;
        int Z = z % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;

        return new Vector3i(X, Y, Z);
    }

    public void MakeDirty(BufferType buffer, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        Vector3i regionalPosition = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

        regions[regionalPosition.X, regionalPosition.Y, regionalPosition.Z].QueueForBuild(buffer);
    }
```

If you need any more of the source I'll post it :D

Any ideas?

**Edit 1:**

```
    public bool InBounds(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if ((x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0) ||
            x >= size.X || y >= size.Y || z >= size.Z)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Exists(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int[] regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            int[] region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            return !(regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].Blocks[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]].BlockType == BlockType.none);
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void SetLight(int x, int y, int z, int light)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int[] regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            int[] region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].QueueForBuild(BufferType.All);
            regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].Blocks[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]].Light = (byte)light;
        }
    }

    public int GetLight(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            // ARRAYS start from ZERO
            // LOGIC starts from ONE

            int[] regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            int[] region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            return regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].Blocks[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]].Light;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        Block block = GetBlock(x, y, z);

        return block;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int[] regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            int[] region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            return regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].Blocks[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]];
        }

        return new Block(BlockType.none);
    }

    public void RemoveBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        int[] regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
        int[] region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

        Block block = new Block(regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].Blocks[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]].BlockType);

        regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].QueueForBuild(block);
        regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].Blocks[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]].BlockType = BlockType.none;

        lighting.BlockRemoved(block, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(Block block, Vector3 position)
    {
        //position += new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        AddBlock(block, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(Block block, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int[] regionalPosition = GetRegionalPosition(x, y, z);
            int[] region = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

            regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].Blocks[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]].BlockType = block.BlockType;

            if (lighting != null)
            {
                lighting.BlockAdded(block, x, y, z);

                if (GetBlock(x, y, z).BlockType == BlockType.waterStill)
                {
                    regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Water);
                    fuilds.WaterQueue.Enqueue(new Flow(x, y, z, 16));
                }
                else
                {
                    regions[region[0], region[1], region[2]].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Solid);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] GetRegionPosition(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int regionx = x == 0 ? 0 : x / Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;
        int regiony = y == 0 ? 0 : y / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;
        int regionz = z == 0 ? 0 : z / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;

        return new int[] {regionx, regiony, regionz};
    }

    public int[] GetRegionalPosition(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int regionx = x == 0 ? 0 : x / Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;
        int X = x % Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;

        int regiony = y == 0 ? 0 : y / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;
        int Y = y % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;

        int regionz = z == 0 ? 0 : z / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;
        int Z = z % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;

        return new int[] { regionx, regiony, regionz };
    }

    public void MakeDirty(BufferType buffer, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int[] regionalPosition = GetRegionPosition(x, y, z);

        regions[regionalPosition[0], regionalPosition[1], regionalPosition[2]].QueueForBuild(buffer);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        blockRenderer.Draw(player, this);
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

OK, here is the new code:

```
    public bool InBounds(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if ((x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0) ||
            x >= size.X || y >= size.Y || z >= size.Z)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Exists(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            return !(regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType == BlockType.none);
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void SetLight(int x, int y, int z, int light)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(BufferType.All);

            regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].Light = (byte)light;
        }
    }

    public int GetLight(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            // ARRAYS start from ZERO
            // LOGIC starts from ONE

            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            return regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].Light;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        Block block = GetBlock(x, y, z);

        return block;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);



            return regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ];
        }

        return new Block(BlockType.none);
    }

    public void RemoveBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
        int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

        regionX = regionalX = x;
        regionY = regionalY = y;
        regionZ = regionalZ = z;

        GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
        GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

        Block block = new Block(regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType);

        regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(block);
        regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType = BlockType.none;

        lighting.BlockRemoved(block, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(Block block, Vector3 position)
    {
        //position += new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        AddBlock(block, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(Block block, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType = block.BlockType;

            if (lighting != null)
            {
                lighting.BlockAdded(block, x, y, z);

                if (GetBlock(x, y, z).BlockType == BlockType.waterStill)
                {
                    regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Water);
                    fuilds.WaterQueue.Enqueue(new Flow(x, y, z, 16));
                }
                else
                {
                    regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Solid);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetRegionPosition(ref int x, ref int y, ref int z)
    {
        x = x == 0 ? 0 : x / Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;
        y = y == 0 ? 0 : y / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;
        z = z == 0 ? 0 : z / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;
    }

    public void GetRegionalPosition(ref int x, ref int y, ref int z)
    {
        int regionx = x == 0 ? 0 : x / Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;
        x = x % Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;

        int regiony = y == 0 ? 0 : y / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;
        y = y % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;

        int regionz = z == 0 ? 0 : z / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;
        z = z % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;
    }

    public void MakeDirty(BufferType buffer, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
        int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

        regionX = regionalX = x;
        regionY = regionalY = y;
        regionZ = regionalZ = z;

        GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

        regions[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].QueueForBuild(buffer);
    }
```

But this still generates a similar report:

[image]

**Edit 3:**

```
    public bool InBounds(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        return !((x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0) || x >= size.X || y >= size.Y || z >= size.Z);
    }

    public bool Exists(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            return !(regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType == BlockType.none);
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void SetLight(int x, int y, int z, int light)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(BufferType.All);

            regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].Light = (byte)light;
        }
    }

    public int GetLight(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            // ARRAYS start from ZERO
            // LOGIC starts from ONE

            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            return regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].Light;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        Block block = GetBlock(x, y, z);

        return block;
    }

    public Block GetBlock(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);



            return regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ];
        }

        return new Block(BlockType.none);
    }

    public void RemoveBlock(Vector3 position)
    {
        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
        int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

        regionX = regionalX = x;
        regionY = regionalY = y;
        regionZ = regionalZ = z;

        GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
        GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

        BlockType blockType = regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType;

        regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(blockType);
        regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType = BlockType.none;

        lighting.BlockRemoved(blockType, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(BlockType blockType, Vector3 position)
    {
        //position += new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        int x = (int)Math.Floor(position.X);
        int y = (int)Math.Floor(position.Y);
        int z = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.Z);

        AddBlock(blockType, x, y, z);
    }

    public void AddBlock(BlockType block, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (InBounds(x, y, z))
        {
            int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
            int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

            regionX = regionalX = x;
            regionY = regionalY = y;
            regionZ = regionalZ = z;

            GetRegionPosition(ref regionX, ref regionY, ref regionZ);
            GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

            regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType = block;

            if (lighting != null)
            {
                lighting.BlockAdded(block, x, y, z);

                if (GetBlock(x, y, z).BlockType == BlockType.waterStill)
                {
                    regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Water);
                    fuilds.WaterQueue.Enqueue(new Flow(x, y, z, 16));
                }
                else
                {
                    regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].QueueForBuild(BufferType.Solid);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetRegionPosition(ref int x, ref int y, ref int z)
    {
        x = x / Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;
        y = y / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;
        z = z / Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;
    }

    public void GetRegionalPosition(ref int x, ref int y, ref int z)
    {
        x = x % Variables.REGION_SIZE_X;

        y = y % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Y;

        z = z % Variables.REGION_SIZE_Z;
    }

    public void MakeDirty(BufferType buffer, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int regionX, regionY, regionZ;
        int regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ;

        regionX = regionalX = x;
        regionY = regionalY = y;
        regionZ = regionalZ = z;

        GetRegionalPosition(ref regionalX, ref regionalY, ref regionalZ);

        regions[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].QueueForBuild(buffer);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, it's pretty simple. The good bit is, once you fix this stuff it'll perform a couple of orders of magnitude better ;)

The first rule is that for functions that are frequently used and perform read operations, you can't afford to allocate memory if you want your game to actually function or perform at an interactive level. You can't afford to allocate a vector every time you want to find out which part of the array is storing the block you want.

**GetRegionalPosition/GetRegionPosition/GetBlock**

None of these should ever allocate memory on the heap.

If you have a block of voxels, just use a 1 dimensional array, and you can use something simple for the location within that block:

width * height * z + height * x + y

That will be an integer location, and you won't have to pass around objects for the location. Since integers are primitives, they're allocated on the stack, so they're safe, temporary objects are the enemy.

An improvement of this is to use shift operators if the size of your chunks are powers of two. I'm happy to walk you through that later, but first we need to get rid of those allocations.

It's ok to allocate objects in response to use input, or for non-frequent events, but it'll come back to bite you if it's occurring in any frequently running code.

If you're writing a game on a garbage collected VM (like C#/Java), you should feel physical pain at any point that you allocate an object.

**GetBlock**

At any point you want a class that represents the block, you really cant afford to allocate it everytime. In order to avoid allocations, the only sane way to approach it is to have a single class instance for each block type, and all methods that use it and depend on it's location pass in the (x,y,z) that the block is at. To go with this you should also have an array in static space that allows you to lookup blocks based on their ids.

Happy to clarify anything I've skipped over or written confusingly.

**In Response to Edit #3**

In "public void AddBlock(BlockType block, int x, int y, int z)"

```
regions[regionX, regionY, regionZ].Blocks[regionalX, regionalY, regionalZ].BlockType = block;
```

I'm guessing this block object has a whole bunch of methods for block type, lighting and extra data etc. This means you're storing thousands of individual block objects. Your garbage collector hates you for this, and it causes an extra level of indirection (chasing pointers) which is a bad thing for memory locatlity.

At some point you're going to want to switch to just using a handful of primitive arrays:

Different language, but same deal:

```
var blockIds = new Array[Byte](Chunk.blockSize)
var data = new Array[Byte](Chunk.blockSize)

var sunLight = new Array[Byte](Chunk.blockSize)
var torchLight =new Array[Byte](Chunk.blockSize)
```

The results from the fluid flow profile aren't surprising. Any local water modal is a can of worms in terms of run time complexity. There isn't a guarantee that you can have a water model like that and have decent performance at the same time.

world.addBlock taking 10% (which also involves your lighting system) doesn't look too bad.

I'd move to primitive arrays away from objects and see how much of an improvement that gives you. I'd also move to having a placeholder empty Region that returns only empty blocks so you can remove inBounds checking from your common methods. As part of this, you'd increase your region array to be always have padding on the sides, and slot the placeholder empty region in to all of the non-loaded slots.

This means that all of your actual world would be surrounded by the placeholder empty region, and you would never need to check bounds, removing the last bit of branching from your read  operations.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are getting at... So basicly I just have to use primitive types like an array of interger. Ill post what I mean in the main post, the strange thing is when I change everything to arrays the world generation is not working properly, can you see anything I have done wrong and if I am going about doing this correctly?

Comment: Arrays aren't primitives. Arrays are an object that houses primitives. The rule is that you're not allowed to use the "new" word ;)

Comment: OK, posted some new (haha) code above without using the new keyword :)... But it appears be even more so CPU intensive.

Comment: There's still a bunch I can point out, but first. If there's work to be done, the CPU should always be at 100%. What FPS are you getting, and is vsync off or on?

Comment: vsync is off, I only get lag when I place blocks such as lava and water, and occasionally normal blocks. When I place water the fps gets as low as 15fps and generally the fps - on average - is at 500fps. If would would like ill post the water flowing code.

Comment: For your GetRegionPosition function, you don't need the conditional. 0 divided by anything is 0 so you can just go ahead and divide your inputs. In your GetRegionalPosition, you don't need to calculate the regionx, regiony, and regionz variables because those are never used. Your InBounds function can just directly return the negation of the if statement's condition, though I am not sure if the optimizer would optimize that out(I assume you have optimizations on). Also, if you only have performance problems in specific situations, use the profiler only in those situations for more accuracy.

Comment: If vsync is off, then you're always going to be at 100%, and the profiler will just find the most common methods. If the lag is only occuring with block placement, then that's the bit you should be profiling. Lighting and liquid algorithms are very easy to make laggy/slow. There's still a bunch of improvements (such as what Chewy found), but we're probably not looking at the problem area. CPU at 100% is normal and good (unless you have vsync and you're not doing much).

Comment: Well, my fuild algorythim I will post above, so will I an updated version of the profiler output.

Comment: Oh, and I also implemented a few things Chewy suggested.

Comment: OK, I implemented it with just plain arrays, no objects (besides the arrays themselves) and there is NO difference in performace whatsoever. Note before I was using structs to hold the blockType and lighting value. So I created a seperate array for each. But to no avail...

Comment: Is there a reason you use a 2 layer organization for storing blocks but don't store both sets of coordinates in the block? It looks like your bottleneck is that your coordinates stored in the block are constantly converted to your 2 layer coordinates. If you stored the region and regional position inside the block or you just did away with the 2 layer system you might get better results. You either need to reduce the number of GetBlock calls or reduce the amount of work it does. As Michael said, an empty border gets rid of the InBounds check so whats left is the coordinate conversion.

Comment: Got it working, I just added a boolean to the addBlock function asking if the block should be flowable (ie add it to the water queue) so when you initally place it it is true, but for every other block it is false, so we don't end up with a ton of infinite loops :)